# Append SVG element to an existing SVG element using JS

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to append SVG element circle to an existing SVG element , i want to circle to sit on top of map i.e overlay but i am unable to do it properly , i  have created JSfiddle for it .Please let me know how to achieve this.

[MY code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/VinayJS/jCxLe/)

How to append at exact co ordinate i am using below code

```
document.getElementById('us').appendChild(c1);
```

Comment: You are appending it correctly. The thing is you are not calling create() function anywhere...

Comment: I have updated the fiddle, method is called once you do mouse over the  map.Please let me know to place it at exact location.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove onmouseover attribute from html and bind mouseover event in javascript code, something like this pseudocode:

```
var item = document.getElementById('id');
item.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    var x = getXPosition();
    var y = getYPosition();
    circleElement.setAttribute('cx', x);
    circleElement.setAttribute('cy', y);
}, false);
```

You should also show/hide element when needed with css classes, inline style or any other method.